# vbScript - Do While Not "Or"

Tags: loops, vbscript, inputbox

I know I had this working somehow yesterday but end of the day I mistakenly closed the changes without saving. Today I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a loop with InputBox and only want to accept 2 potential answers, in this case apple or orange should exit the loop.

```
    Do
    myValue = InputBox("Enter something")
    Loop While Not myValue = "apple" Or myValue = "orange"
```

The above will only exit the loop if the first value is entered but not the second. If I add a "Not" for the second value as well like the following, then it doesnt exit the loop regardless of what I type.

```
    Do
    myValue = InputBox("Enter something")
    Loop While Not myValue = "apple" Or Not myValue = "orange"
```

I know this is has to be something obvious but I think I've looked at this same code too long to see it. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want an `and`...

```
Do
myValue = InputBox("Enter something")
Loop While Not myValue = "apple" And Not myValue = "orange"
```

Not ands and Not ors *are* confusing, but if you work it through, you'll figure it out. Example input: apple

`NOT "apple" = "apple"` is `FALSE`, and `NOT "apple" = "orange"` is `TRUE`. If you use an `OR`, `TRUE or FALSE` evaluates to `TRUE`. Therefore the loop continues. But if you use an `AND`, the whole statement evaluates to `FALSE`, which allows an exit.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something obvious I was doing wrong. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Why not translate English into VBScript:

```
I want to ask the user until the input is "apple" or "orange"
```

==>

```
  Dim sInp
  Do
     sInp = InputBox("Enter something")
     WScript.Echo "+", sInp
  Loop Until sInp = "apple" Or sInp = "orange"
  WScript.Echo sInp
```

sample output:

```
+ banana
+ apple
apple
=============

+ pear
+ orange
orange
=============
```